# devise generating views error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, view

I've got a problem with **devise gem**, when I enter *rails generate devise:install* command there is an error:

```
/home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize': unin
itialized constant View (NameError)
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `const
antize'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:87:in `to'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in `modules'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `strategies'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise.rb:166:in `register'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:92:in `block in devise_for'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:91:in `each'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.1.rc1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:91:in `devise_for'
        from /home/ofca/Praca/inzynierka/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `eval_block'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:235:in `draw'
        from /home/ofca/Praca/inzynierka/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in load_paths
'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_up
dated'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <modul
e:Finisher>'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `call'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>
'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/ofca/Praca/inzynierka/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision  32553) on Linux. And db is postgres. 
Here is the line mentioned in the first line of the error log:

```
constant = constant.const_defined?(name, false) ? constant.const_get(name) : constant.const_missing(name)
```

Oh, and I tried other combinations of this command: rails generate devise:install, rails g devise_install and it gives me the same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Devise that is not even meant to be used in production (it is a release candidate!). Please update your Devise version.

Comment: thanks! this solved the problem:) btw. Jose - I'm the guy who enter the class with Your bday cake at Rupy :) it was nice2meet You in person [sorry4offtopic;)]

Answer (score 0):

solution: add to gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

Comment: You should rather leave `gem 'devise'` in your Gemfile and do `bundle update` instead.

Comment: I ran it, but it doesn't help me :/

Comment: Sorry, that would be `bundle update devise`. If this still doesn't work, you may have another gem that depends on devise. In that case, you should post the full contents of your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.